# Django error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' while trying to delete to-do list item

Tags: django

I am trying to make simple to-do list where user can add or delete list items. With adding everything works fine, but when I trying to delete item nothing happens or I get erorr: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Code:

```
#Views.py

def tasks(request):
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if "add" in request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                save_it = form.save()
        if "delete" in request.POST:
            comments_id = request.POST['idcomment']
            comments_object = Comment.objects.get(id=comments_id)
            comments_object.delete()
        return render(request, 'task-form.html', {
        'form': form, 'comments': comments,
        })
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'Task-form.html', {
        'form': form, 'comments': comments,
        })
```

And Django template is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Tasks</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add">
{% for a in comments %}
    <h3>{{ a.body}}</h3>
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idcomment" id="{{a.id}}" />
{% endfor %}
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because `comments_id` is an empty string, because `request.POST['idcomment']` is an empty string, and you can't convert an empty string to an int (which is what happens when you do `Comment.objects.get(id=comments_id)`). Why is it empty? Let's look at your template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idcomment" id="{{a.id}}" />
```

You gave the input an id, but you never gave it a value. Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idcomment" id="{{a.id}}" value="{{a.id}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But now I get CSRF verification failed.